# How do I hide part of a THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry when it's inside another object?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a mesh made of a `THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry` (a water surface) and on that surface is another object (a boat). My problem is that when the boat goes a little into the water, you see the water suddenly appearing inside the boat (because of the higher y value).

How can I solve this?

I was thinking in terms of calculating the dimensions of the insides of the boat and trying to pass them on to the shader of the water surface. (If the point is inside, hide it.) Is this the best approach? And how can i do this?

EDIT: The water should overlap (e.g. shown in front of) the sides of the boat. To clearify:

```
  Current situation:            Desired situation:

B        A
     |         |                  |         |
-----|---------|--------     -----|         |--------
     |_________|                  |_________|
```

From [A] you should not see water inside the boat object and from [B] you shouldn't see the lower part of the boat.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable the depth writing for the water surface. Check the following sample. Let's say the blue plain is water and the red one is a boat.

```
//codepen.io/OlxandrPopov/pen/xwVBKg
```

Comment: For some reasons I'm unable to post links to codepen.io, so just prefix the link above with http:

Comment: Thank you! The only problem with this, is that the water should show in front of the side of the boat object when you look at it from the side.. :S